# Setting query parameters and reloading the page as checkboxes are selected

Tags: jquery, ruby, ajax, twitter-bootstrap, sinatra

I have a set of checkboxes (that currently do not do anything) on my homepage:

```
    <ul class="nav nav-list">
      <li class="nav-header">Questions</li>
      <li><label class="checkbox"> <input type="checkbox"> All </label></li>
      <li><label class="checkbox"> <input type="checkbox"> Funny </label></li>
      <li><label class="checkbox"> <input type="checkbox"> Popular </label></li>
      <li><label class="checkbox"> <input type="checkbox"> Helpful </label></li>
    </ul>
```

I wrote a simple back-end right now that supports URLs like: http://myhomepage.com?funny=1&popular=1 to show questions that are both funny AND popular, for example. There's a query parameter for each option. The server checks the query parameters and returns an updated the `@questions` variable with the appropriate set. The view iterates through `@questions` and displayed them one by one.

Here's my goal: 
As the user selects checkboxes (e.g. funny and popular), I'd love to have the homepage make calls to the server (AJAX?) to update the set of questions displayed on the page to match the user's selections (ideally with a spinner displayed as stuff is loading). I can use jQuery or just about anything else.

How would I go about doing this? For the back-end, I'm using Sinatra / Ruby, Bootstrap for the UI, and I can use jQuery or just about anything else you recommend :)

Comment: So you're just missing the js code for ajax firing/handling?  What would a response look like to a request at the sample URL?

Comment: hm, as i've noted above: http://myhomepage.com?funny=1&popular=1 will show questions that are both funny AND popular, for example. does that help? not sure if that is what you are looking for though!

Comment: I mean what structure would the response have - would it be a JSON encoded object, or just an HTML snippet?  Can you provide a sample response in your post?  Even better, can you provide the backend code that builds the response?

Comment: This can be achieved using the [jQuery.ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) method.

Comment: Also, I'm not seeing a submit trigger - what tells the browser that the user is finished selecting so it should submit to the server for the next batch of questions?

Comment: @PinnyM: Ah, the response is just the @questions variable which is an Array `Array: #<Questions::Question:0x007fbffb5237f0 @attrs={:created_at=>"Tue Dec 11 22:46:07 +0000 2012", :id=>27, :id_str=>"27", :questiontext=>"Is this a question? …`

Comment: @PinnyM I can certainly add a Submit button! As noted above, I'd love it if the browser submits to the server right after select/deselect of each checkbox.

Comment: If the browser updates after selecting one checkbox, where does the new list of questions appear?  If it replaces the current list, then a user can never select more than one checkbox (your example has a user choosing 2 checkboxes)...

Comment: "the response is just the @questions variable" - you can't expect a browser to understand the structure of your ruby objects.  You need to serialize them in some format - JSON is commonly used for this - before using it in the response.

Comment: You can Submit to the server on click in the checkbox this is what I propose in my response; I just suppose that you server return an HTML response if you will use Json Ecoded object you will need to update the script accordingly !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.3.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<ul class="nav nav-list">
      <li class="nav-header">Questions</li>
      <li><label class="checkbox"> <input type="checkbox"> All </label></li>
      <li><label class="checkbox"> <input type="checkbox"> Funny </label></li>
      <li><label class="checkbox"> <input type="checkbox"> Popular </label></li>
      <li><label class="checkbox"> <input type="checkbox"> Helpful </label></li>
    </ul>

    <div id="result"></div>

<script>

$(function(){
var Url;
$("input[type='checkbox']").click(function(){
    Url = 'http://myhomepage.com?';
    $.each($("input[type='checkbox']"),function(){

    if(this.checked)
    {
        var html = $.trim($(this).parent().html().replace('<input type="checkbox"> ',''));
        Url = Url + html + "=1&";
    }

    });
    console.log(Url);
    $.ajax({
      url: Url,
      success: function(data) {
        $('#result').html(data);
         alert('Load was performed.');
      }
    });

});

});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: this is great! what about when a checkbox is deselected though? working thru that now...